# SQL Invalid object name for temp table with openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, temp-tables, openquery

SQL query is as below:

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR (8000)
SET @Sql='XXXXXX'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL DROP  TABLE #Orders
EXEC('SELECT * INTO  #Orders FROM OPENQUERY(TMM10, ''' +@Sql+ ''')')  
--Until now everything seems OK

SELECT * FROM  #Order
```

This statement runs well until insertion for temp table. Result shows "49134 rows have been inserted". However, error shows "invalid object name #Order", which does exist in Tempdb.

Comment: The temp table gets created inside the scope of your `EXEC` and not outside of it, so yeah, it doesn't exists when you want to use it in your `SELECT`  later

Comment: I see. Changed to global temp table

Answer (score 0):

Scope issue; I modified your test to demonstrate a way around it.

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR (8000)
SET @Sql='XXXXXX'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Orders') IS NOT NULL DROP  TABLE #Orders
CREATE TABLE #Orders (ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Orders
        ( ID )

EXEC('SELECT 1')  
--Until now everything seems OK

SELECT * FROM  #Orders
```